# Basic string in java programming

Tags: java

So I have an assignment that I'm a little confused on. Here is the prompt:

A table of contents in many books use periods to align text with the page numbers.  These are called “dot leaders”.  You are to write a program that accepts from the user a chapter title and a page number.  **Then you will output these to a line that contains exactly fifty characters.  The space between the title and the page number will be filled with periods (“.”).**

Sample Output:

Enter the title:  An Introduction to Java
Enter the page number:  5

An Introduction to Java……………………….5

Enter the title:  Simple Data Types
Enter the page number:  27

Simple Data Types………………………..…27

The part I'm confused on is the part of the prompt that says "Then you will output these to a line that contains exactly fifty characters.  The space between the title and the page number will be filled with periods (“.”)." I don't really know how to make sure that the line contains exactly fifty characters, or the way to go about it. I got the first parts with entering the title and the page number. It's the last line that I'm stuck on in the sample output. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Prog590
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i<=2; i++)
        {
            Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter the title: ");
            String str = kbReader.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter the page number: ");
            int num = kbReader.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

}

Could someone show me or provide a start for me to begin the last line of code to get the required output? I don't really know how to print the final line of the sample output or make sure it has exactly fifty characters. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: A good idea is always to read the API doc. Here you can look up the String class and you will find that it has a length() method.

Comment: I think you can get an answer here, but you should maybe buy a programming book and read it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample to get start for you,

```
System.out.println(str);

for (i = str.length(); i < 50; i++){
    System.out.print(".");
}

System.out.println(num);
```

So basically

1. GEt the length of title and page number
2. print `title`
3. print dots `(50 - (title length + page number length))`
4. print `page number`

I hope this helps. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the space that is taken by the title itself and the page number. Let us call the length of the title `tl` and the length of the printed page number `pl`. Let us further call the number of dots to print `nd`. Then it is obviously so that:

```
 tl + nd + pl = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use such code snippet

```
String str; //Title
int num; //page
int counter = 50 - str.length() + num.toString().length();
for (int i=0; i<counter; i++){
    System.out.print(".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the length of each string. Print the title then the dots and finally your page number. You should change num to string;

example if num were a string.

```
    System.out.print(str);
    for(int i = str.length()+num.length();i<=50;i++){
        System.out.print(".");
    }
    System.out.print(num);
```